# Service to send Bitcoins or Altcoins over a specific amount of time? Doing it Decentralized?

Tags: altcoin, payment

Is there a service that lets you send Bitcoins or more interestingly Altcoins to an address over a set amount of time. Say for example I wanted to give allowance to my daughter every week for the next year at $10 each time. This might have to be done centralized or how would this be implemented on a decentralized manner?

Answer (score 1):

You can just publish a bunch of transactions with [a particular nlocktime](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_documentation#tx). Say you wanted to give your daughter an allowance of 0.1 BTC/week for a whole year. You can create one transaction with a locktime of next monday for 0.1 BTC, another transaction with a locktime of the monday after that for 0.1 BTC and so on for a whole year. The way bitcoin works, she'll receive the amounts every monday.

At any time, you can create a transaction to yourself to nullify some or all of the future transactions. Many altcoins will also have this feature.

Now, if you want a constant dollar amount and not a bitcoin amount, that actually will require a service. Doing that in a decentralized way is going to be really tough since exchange rates by their nature tend to be centralized.

Here's how you can make an nlocktime transaction using the excellent [btcd library](https://github.com/btcsuite/btcd) in go:

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/hex"
    "fmt"

    "github.com/btcsuite/btcd/btcec"
    "github.com/btcsuite/btcd/chaincfg"
    "github.com/btcsuite/btcd/txscript"
    "github.com/btcsuite/btcd/wire"
    "github.com/btcsuite/btcutil"
)

func main() {

    // Ordinarily the private key would come from whatever storage mechanism
    // is being used, but for this example just hard code it.
    wif, err := btcutil.DecodeWIF(
        "<testnet private key in WIF format here>")
    )
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    compressed := false

    privKey := wif.PrivKey
    pubKey := privKey.PubKey()
    serializedPubKey := pubKey.SerializeCompressed()
    if !compressed {
        serializedPubKey = pubKey.SerializeUncompressed()
    }
    pubKeyHash := btcutil.Hash160(serializedPubKey)
    addr, err := btcutil.NewAddressPubKeyHash(pubKeyHash,
        &chaincfg.TestNet3Params)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    txStr, err := hex.DecodeString("<testnet tx that contains the utxo in hex here>")

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    rbuf := bytes.NewReader(txStr)
    var originTx wire.MsgTx
    err = originTx.Deserialize(rbuf)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Deserialize error %v\n", err)
        return
    }
    originTxHash := originTx.TxSha()

    // Create the transaction to redeem the fake transaction.
    redeemTx := wire.NewMsgTx()

    // Add the input(s) the redeeming transaction will spend.  There is no
    // signature script at this point since it hasn't been created or signed
    // yet, hence nil is provided for it.
    prevOut := wire.NewOutPoint(&originTxHash, 0)
    txIn := wire.NewTxIn(prevOut, nil)
    txIn.Sequence = 0
    redeemTx.AddTxIn(txIn)

    addr2, err := btcutil.DecodeAddress("<destination testnet addr here>",
        &chaincfg.TestNet3Params)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    pkScript, err := txscript.PayToAddrScript(addr2)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    txOut := wire.NewTxOut(93889960000, pkScript)
    redeemTx.AddTxOut(txOut)

    // unix time of when the tx output will be unlocked here
    redeemTx.LockTime = 1442802900

    // Sign the redeeming transaction.
    lookupKey := func(a btcutil.Address) (*btcec.PrivateKey, bool, error) {
        // Ordinarily this function would involve looking up the private
        // key for the provided address, but since the only thing being
        // signed in this example uses the address associated with the
        // private key from above, simply return it with the compressed
        // flag set since the address is using the associated compressed
        // public key.
        //
        // NOTE: If you want to prove the code is actually signing the
        // transaction properly, uncomment the following line which
        // intentionally returns an invalid key to sign with, which in
        // turn will result in a failure during the script execution
        // when verifying the signature.
        //
        // privKey.D.SetInt64(12345)
        return privKey, compressed, nil
    }
    // Notice that the script database parameter is nil here since it isn't
    // used.  It must be specified when pay-to-script-hash transactions are
    // being signed.
    sigScript, err := txscript.SignTxOutput(&chaincfg.TestNet3Params,
        redeemTx, 0, originTx.TxOut[0].PkScript, txscript.SigHashAll,
        txscript.KeyClosure(lookupKey), nil, nil)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    redeemTx.TxIn[0].SignatureScript = sigScript

    var buf bytes.Buffer
    err = redeemTx.Serialize(&buf)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Serialize error %v", err)
        return
    }

    // Prove that the transaction has been validly signed by executing the
    // script pair.
    flags := txscript.ScriptBip16 | txscript.ScriptVerifyDERSignatures |
        txscript.ScriptStrictMultiSig |
        txscript.ScriptDiscourageUpgradableNops
    vm, err := txscript.NewEngine(originTx.TxOut[0].PkScript, redeemTx, 0,
        flags)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    if err := vm.Execute(); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    fmt.Printf("Transaction successfully signed %v\n", hex.EncodeToString(buf.Bytes()))

}
```

Comment: isnt nlocktime still pending to be released in a later version? or can u use it already? do you know if there is a sample code of how to do this?

Comment: possibly relevant? https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/5783/transactions-with-a-wait-time-using-nlocktime

Comment: nlocktime has worked for a while. I'll add some sample code in the answer.

Comment: when creating this transaction. does this mean this future transaction gets stored somewhere until it hits the block height before it gets executed?

Comment: Generally, it stays in the mempool until it can be included in a block on the network. It's possible for it to disappear, so you would need to rebroadcast right before the right time.