# Which clients support nLockTime?

Tags: client, locktime

I want to use nLockTime, but I don't know what clients support it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No standard client supports NLockTime directly AFAIK.

You can create raw transactions with bitcoind and then use a standard client to transmit them to the network in the method described [here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/5783/transactions-with-a-wait-time-using-nlocktime)